# Most efficient way to search very large text file and output lines matching any of a very large number of terms to another file

Tags: perl, search, large-files

I have ~15 million line file. I have another file with around 500,000 lines. I want to keep lines from the large file where a particular field matches the line in the second file. The large file is tab delimited.

How would you do this in Perl, for example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might benefit from using a csv module to parse the data from the large file. It might also be overkill, and more trouble than it's worth, that you must judge for yourself. Be aware that [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::CSV_XS) used below may alter your data to comply to csv standards, and there are many options to tweak what your output looks like.

This is a basic script that might get you started.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use Text::CSV_XS;

open my $lookup, '<', "lookupfile";
my %lookup;
while (<$lookup>) {
    next if /^\s*$/;   # remove empty lines
    chomp;             # remove newline
    $lookup{$_} = 1;
}
close $lookup;

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new ({
    binary    => 1, 
    eol       => $/,
    sep_char  => "\t",
});
open my $bigfile, '<', 'bigfile';
while (my $row = $csv->getline ($bigfile)) {
    if (defined ($lookup{$row->[0]})) {
        $csv->print(\*STDOUT, $row);
    }
}
```

If you feel secure that your data will not contain embedded tabs, you might get away with simply splitting the line on tabs, instead of using Text::CSV_XS:

```
while (<$bigfile>) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split /\t/;
    if (defined $lookup{$row[0]}) {
        print "$_\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I somehow missed your comment there about skipping empty/whitespace lines.

Answer (score 3):

I'd populate a hash keyed on the values from the second file. Set the values to `1`.

Then I'd do a simple `while(<FILE>)` loop doing lookups in the hash on the key field. If there is an entry in the hash, print the line. Else move on.

Perl's hash lookups are pretty quick, doing it 15 million times ought to be alright.

Comment: Perl should easily do several millions of hash lookups (on not-ridiculously long strings) per second on any current CPU.